# how to run multiple tell commands that open new window in one bash script?

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, applescript

I tried

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript -e '
  tell application "Terminal"
  do script "cd ~/www/service/code&& npm install && npm run dev"
  activate
  end tell

  tell application "Terminal"
  do script "cd ~/www/app-ui && npm install && npm start"
  activate
  end tell


'
```

Nothing happened, no error either. Where went wrong?

Comment: Do you really need to use osascript for this?

Comment: Why a second `tell application "Terminal"` block when you can have both `do script` commands in the same `tell application "Terminal"` block, or gang the command together in the same `do script` command, e.g. `do script "command; command"`

Comment: @user3439894, the space is good form, but not strictly necessary. Try running `echo foo&&echo bar` -- you'll see both commands run.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, Yeah, I actually know that... wasn't thinking... haven't had my second cup of coffee yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create a separate script for each piece you want to run in a separate window.

```
#!/bin/sh

cat >scriptA <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/www/service/code && npm install && npm run dev
EOF
chmod +x scriptA

cat >scriptB <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/www/service/code && npm install && npm run dev
EOF
chmod +x scriptB

open -a Terminal.app scriptA
open -a Terminal.app scriptB
```

Comment: sry, crazy new for shell.... but `open -a Terminal.app scriptA
open -a Terminal.app scriptB` cant be executed together no? I tried it, nothing happened when I put them into one .sh file , if I can't run all the script in one stroke I feel very unsatisfied...

Comment: Works fine for me. Does need to be two lines, of course.

Comment: The *exact* code I ran myself is at https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/c5285db801b0344121bc8a88db6d2125 -- pops up one window containing `HELLO`, and another containing `WORLD`.

Comment: ahhhh man, I thought you literarily means make two files which I did lol its actually one script. gotcha, yes, it works very well!!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well -- it *does* create two files. When this script is run, it creates one file named `scriptA` and another file named `scriptB`, and then starts two terminals -- one running scriptA, one running scriptB. In a real-world use case, I'd expect you to just have them already pre-created rather than doing that at runtime.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was doing `||` instead, that's why it wasnt working. thanks a llot!

Comment: and interesting stuff why if I name the file into `.sh` it won't work, even the file is there? I made two script A and script B in `.sh`

Comment: So, I'd argue that [`.sh` extensions are bad form](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/), but as long as they have a valid shebang and executable permissions (`chmod +x`), they should still work.